# Is there a more accurate way of determining the minimum version needed?

Tags: perl, version

I'm trying to learn Perl.  I write a script and then try to find out what the minimum version of Perl that's needed to run the script.

I was told Perl comes with a program called [`perlver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::MinimumVersion) which will determine the minimum version needed based on both syntax and by what's explicitly stated.

I have the following code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use autodie;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

say "Hey";
exit 0;
```

But when I run the script through [`perlver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::MinimumVersion), I get the following output:

```
[me@here PERL] $ perlver ex6-1 


   ------------------------------------  
 | file  | explicit | syntax | external |
 | ------------------------------------ |
 | ex6-1 | ~        | v5.8.0 | n/a      |
 | ------------------------------------ |
 | Minimum explicit version : ~         |
 | Minimum syntax version   : v5.8.0    |
 | Minimum version of perl  : v5.8.0    |
   ------------------------------------  

[me@here PERL] $
```

It says that the minimum version based on sytax is `v5.8.0`.  But when I add `use v5.8.0` to the script, I get an error:

```
String found where operator expected at ./ex6-1 line 16, near "say "Hey"" (#1)
    (S syntax) The Perl lexer knows whether to expect a term or an operator.
    If it sees what it knows to be a term when it was expecting to see an
    operator, it gives you this warning.  Usually it indicates that an
    operator or delimiter was omitted, such as a semicolon.

    (Do you need to predeclare say?) (#2)
    (S syntax) This is an educated guess made in conjunction with the message
    "%s found where operator expected".  It often means a subroutine or module
    name is being referenced that hasn't been declared yet.  This may be
    because of ordering problems in your file, or because of a missing
    "sub", "package", "require", or "use" statement.  If you're referencing
    something that isn't defined yet, you don't actually have to define the
    subroutine or package before the current location.  You can use an empty
    "sub foo;" or "package FOO;" to enter a "forward" declaration.

syntax error at ./ex6-1 line 16, near "say "Hey""
Execution of ./ex6-1 aborted due to compilation errors (#3)
    (F) Probably means you had a syntax error.  Common reasons include:

        A keyword is misspelled.
        A semicolon is missing.
        A comma is missing.
        An opening or closing parenthesis is missing.
        An opening or closing brace is missing.
        A closing quote is missing.

    Often there will be another error message associated with the syntax
    error giving more information.  (Sometimes it helps to turn on -w.)
    The error message itself often tells you where it was in the line when
    it decided to give up.  Sometimes the actual error is several tokens
    before this, because Perl is good at understanding random input.
    Occasionally the line number may be misleading, and once in a blue moon
    the only way to figure out what's triggering the error is to call
    perl -c repeatedly, chopping away half the program each time to see
    if the error went away.  Sort of the cybernetic version of 20 questions.

Uncaught exception from user code:
    syntax error at ./ex6-1 line 16, near "say "Hey""
    Execution of ./ex6-1 aborted due to compilation errors.
```

The error suggests that `say` isn't included in the `v5.8.0`.  So how can I accurately find out the minimum required version of Perl needed to run a script?

Or might there be a complete list of Perl functions listed by verison number that I can parse myself to get the minimum version?

Comment: Add `use feature 'say';` in your script and then `perlver script_name.pl` will show the min version **v5.10.0**, I used your exact syntax and got the same error and @ikegami is right.

Comment: *" But when I add use v5.8.0 to the script, I get an error:"* You get an error even without `use v5.8.0`. That code won't compile under any existing version of Perl. You can't just throw nonsense at the utility and hope to get a sensible answer.

Comment: There are hardly any functions that have been added outside of features over time. The only one I know ottomh is `fc`, but I am not sure about that. There are some operators, like `//=`, that have been added later and those don't need `feature`s.

Comment: Is exercise 6 from a book, a tutorial or is it part of a class in school/university? Just curious. I've never seen a tutorial that bothers with the version of Perl, especially not early on. Most of the things are version-agnostic. Perl 5 is very good with not caring about the version you have. Backwards-compatibility is a big issue in the Perl core and on CPAN. That's why new syntax doesn't just appear, it needs to be turned on explicitly. That's what the `use version` pragma is all about.

Comment: @simbabque: `fc` requires `use feature 'fc'`. Where did you get "exercise 6" from?

Comment: @Borodin haha. Right. Proves my point though. :-) The file name is ex6-1.pl, which sounds a lot like exercise 6. And they have been told stuff. That sounds like a class. Actually I think the question is not bad. It's valid. And they don't know a lot about the language yet. True, they ought have run the program first to see if it works, but still.

Comment: Re "*I was told Perl comes with a program called `perlver`*", It's actually provided by the Perl-MinimumVersion distribution.

Comment: @simbabque, names can't be added to existing namespaces without causing problems, such as breaking a script that has a sub named `say`. That's why new ops are only added to CORE:: by default.

Comment: @Deanie, By the way, even if you program requires a specific version of Perl, it doesn't make it safe to add `use v5.xx;` as that actually changes things. otoh, `require v5.xx;` is safe, or make sure to retest everything after adding `use v5.xx;`.

Answer (score 5):

What is probably confusing you is that, for instance, `use 5.010` (or `use v5.10`) does two things

- It ensures that the version of the current Perl interpreter is at least 5.10. That's what `require 5.010` does
- It does the equivalent of `use feature ':5.10'`, which enables all features available in that version

That means if you add `use 5.010` to your program it will enable, amongst other things, the `say` feature

But without either `use feature 'say'` or `use 5.010` your program won't even compile, so `perlver` will give you the wrong answer

I recommend using `require 5.010` and `use feature 'say'` separately so as to prevent all of the features being enabled whether you want to use them or not, and so polluting your namespace

Comment: So then when they say that `say` is included in `Perl v5.10`, they really mean it's available, but not included?

Comment: @Deanie: I think you've been misled by the comments. It's included in the sense that it's part of the Perl interpreter, but it must be enabled by a `use feature` statement in your program before you can use it. In a very similar way to strictures being part of Perl, but you must `use strict` to enable them. It's up to you whether you think "included" is an appropriate description.

Comment: @Deanie, They mean you can make it available using `use feature qw( say );` or similar. They also mean it's available as `CORE::say` (since 5.12).

Answer (score 4):

Your program isn't valid in any version of Perl.

```
$ perl5.24.0 -e'use utf8; use strict; use autodie; use warnings; say "Hey"; exit 0;'
String found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "say "Hey""
        (Do you need to predeclare say?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "say "Hey""
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

You might as well have used `foo "Hey";`.

```
$ perl5.24.0 -e'use utf8; use strict; use autodie; use warnings; foo "Hey"; exit 0;'
String found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "foo "Hey""
        (Do you need to predeclare foo?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "foo "Hey""
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Start by writing a program that works.

---

On the other hand, let's say your program included the following:

```
use feature qw( say );
say "Hey";
```

This particular program requires 5.10, and `perlver` correctly identifies that 5.10 is required.

```
   ------------------------------------
 | file | explicit | syntax  | external |
 | ------------------------------------ |
 | a.pl | ~        | v5.10.0 | n/a      |
 | ------------------------------------ |
 | Minimum explicit version : ~                             |
 | Minimum syntax version   : v5.10.0                       |
 | Minimum version of perl  : v5.10.0                       |
   ------------------------------------
```

Comment: This isn't true at all.  I can take the above code and change `say "Hey";` to `print "Hey\n";` and it runs as expected.  Can you explain your answer?

Comment: @Deanie, So what? That doesn't affect my answer at all. Your program isn't valid in any version of Perl, and `print "Hey\n";` doesn't prove otherwise!

Comment: `say` is just `print` that adds a `\n` to the end of the statement.  `say` is included in `v5.10`, which means the program can run with `v5.10`.  So `say` does exist.  And I'm using Perl `v5.24` which should have access to `say`.  So why does `perlver` suggest the minimum version is `v5.8.0`?

Comment: @Deanie `say` is not _included_ in 5.10, it's available as an optional feature from 5.10. It's not there automatically.  You need to turn it on.

Comment: No, it's not included in 5.10. `say "Hey";` is just as must a syntax error in 5.10 (and 5.24 as shown in my answer) as it is in 5.8. If you had `use feature qw( say ); say "Hey";`, it would be another story.